# OpenSSL AES encryption with C++ produce different output issue

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I have an issue while using Openssl in my C script where I have to encrypt the same string for a set number of loops, but even with the same iv and key, there are times when the encryption process produces different encrypted output than the rest of the other result, and it happens very frequently, because I need to compare the result of the encryption process (using memcmp) with a set of encrypted string, and the result won't be consistent if it keeps happening. can anybody help me figuring out what's wrong with my code?

this is what I did:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
  string target = "xxx";
    unsigned char* result;
    unsigned char* unzero;
    unzero = new unsigned char[100];
    strcpy((char *) unzero, target.c_str());
    int ciphertext_len;
    result = new unsigned char[100];
    // encryption process
    ciphertext_len = encrypt (unzero, strlen ((char *)unzero), key, iv,result);
    cout<<ciphertext<<<endl;
    }
```

and here is the encryption function:

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
      unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
    {
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
      int len;
      int ciphertext_len;

      if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

      if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

      if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
      ciphertext_len = len;

      if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
      ciphertext_len += len;

      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

      return ciphertext_len;
    }
```

here is the output:

```
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���iPK��U
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
\p`b�@J��A���i
```

notice that there is a difference in the second row, is there anybody that can help me? Thank you

Comment: Is this the result of `cout<<ciphertext<<<endl;` you are showing ? `ciphertext` is not modified in the loop you show .. You properly wanted to print the content returned in `result` ?! If that is the case, you need to find another way to print it, as its binary data that can't be printed that way ..

Comment: A very similar question was posed just yesterday, with an answer here: [C - OpenSSL encryption using CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620525/1380680)

Comment: And the fact that you see garbage isn't bothering you? The binary stream is not null-terminated, hence you've experiencing undefined behavior.